# Why does CancellationTokenSource.Cancel cause my UI to lock up for a few seconds?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, asynchronous

I am writing a winforms application in vb.net (although C# answers would also be acceptable.)

I am trying to cancel a call to `Await Stream.CopyToAsync()`

Please see my greatly simplified code below:

```
Private _CTS As New Threading.CancellationTokenSource

Private Async Sub DBToFile(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim DBStream as stream = GetDBStream()
    Dim FStream As FileStream = File.Create(Path)
    Await DBstream.CopyToAsync(FStream, 81920, _CTS.Token)
End Sub
```

When I call `_CTS.Cancel()` from my UI, it causes it to freeze for a couple of seconds. Why would this be? Even if i call it using `Task.Run(Sub() _CTS.Cancel())`, it makes no difference.

If I decouple the token from the call to `Await DBstream.CopyToAsync(FStream, 81920, _CTS.Token)`, (e.g. just call `Await DBstream.CopyToAsync(FStream)` instead), the freeze does not occur (even though `.Cancel()` is still being called.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you able to figure out (e.g. with some tracing) whether it hangs inside the call to `.Cancel()` (so the call takes long, (which would be surprising)) or as a result of what happens after you called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @tinudu I think I may have narrowed it down.

It seems that the freeze occurs just after the call to `Await Stream.CopyToAsync()`, not during.

I hadn't considered this as nothing much happens after the call to `Await Stream.CopyToAsync()`, *EXCEPT* it is wrapped in a number of `Using` blocks, so there there is a bit of disposal to deal with. I can only assume that this is the cause.

This would also explain why calling _CTS.Cancel() in a separate task doesn't help, as I assume the code after `Await Stream.CopyToAsync()` continues on the original thread.